# Selecting text of same color in using .select() d3js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am have plot of words over X-Y axis .on clicking I want to color all the words in the radius of word clicked.
I am able to color the words on first click but my problem is when i click again on some other part of the plot the previous coloring resets.

```
.on("click", function(d) {
    var text = svg.selectAll("text");
    var threshhold = +document.getElementById("threshhold").value;  

    text.transition()
        .style("fill", function(a) { // <== Add these
            if ((a.xcord)<= (d.xcord +threshhold) &&
                (a.xcord)>= (d.xcord -threshhold) &&
                (a.ycord)<= (d.ycord +threshhold) &&
                (a.ycord)>= (d.ycord -threshhold)) {
                    return document.querySelector('input[name="class"]:checked').value;
            } // <== Add these
        })
        .attr("font-weight", function(a) { // <== Add these
            if ((a.xcord)<= (d.xcord +threshhold) &&
                (a.xcord)>= (d.xcord -threshhold) &&
                (a.ycord)<= (d.ycord +threshhold) &&
                (a.ycord)>= (d.ycord -threshhold)) {
                    return "bold";
            } // <== Add these
        })
});
```

I am using above code to color the text. I think the problem is where i am using `var text = svg.selectAll("text");`

Is there any ways i can select all text elements of same color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the issue is that the color from your previous click is wiped out when you click again, right?

The issue here is that your functions for `fill` and `font-weight` are effectively returning `undefined` if the element doesn't pass the conditional. The easiest option here is probably to use [`selection.filter`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter):

```
.on("click", function(d) {
    var text = svg.selectAll("text");
    var threshhold = +document.getElementById("threshhold").value;  

    text
        .filter(function(a) {
            return (a.xcord) <= (d.xcord +threshhold) &&
                (a.xcord) >= (d.xcord -threshhold) &&
                (a.ycord) <= (d.ycord +threshhold) &&
                (a.ycord) >= (d.ycord -threshhold);
        })
        .transition()
        .style("fill",
            document.querySelector('input[name="class"]:checked').value)
        .attr("font-weight", "bold");
});
```

Note that you don't need functions for the `attr` and `style` values in this case.

As an aside, you're finding text in a bounding box, not a radius - if you wanted the radius check, you could use

```
text
    .filter(function(a) {
        var a2 = Math.pow(a.xcord - d.xcord, 2);
        var b2 = Math.pow(a.ycord - d.ycord, 2);
        return a2 + b2  < threshold * threshold;
    })
```

Good old Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: That worked perfectly well. I am newbie in D3 so didnt know how could I use the filter.Thanks